# Width of Div Will Not Change on Media Query

Tags: css, dynamic, width, media

Here's the html:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

And the css:

```
#test{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:red;    
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
width:calc(100% - 100px);   
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px)
{
.test{
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Essentially, the width of the div will not change on the media query (width drops below 500px). Any suggestions?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rSthC/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in the CSS - it should be #test and not .test in the media query as it's an id and not a class.

Comment: Annoyingly, that works even though the project I'm working on still doesn't.

Comment: Well, I've seemed to have fixed the problem that you've posted on here so can't do any more without extra information!

Comment: You have indeed. Thank you!

Comment: @FinMoorhouse could you set as the answer then please :)